# Google app engine endpoints api python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, webapp2

I am facing a problem in endpoint. I am using google app engine on local machine. I am trying to make a endpoint api. The api is created successfully but when i open explorer and select my api give some parameters to it. It does not return response. In response it said 404 not found

Here is the code:

api.py

```
import endpoints
import protorpc

from ModelClasses import test


import main

@endpoints.api(name="test",version="v1",description="testingapi",hostname="login-test-1208.appspot.com")
class testapi(protorpc.remote.Service):



    @test.method(name="userinsert",path="userinsert",http_method="POST")
    def userinsert(self,request):

        qr = test()
        qr.user = request.user
        qr.passw = request.passw

        qr.put()
        return qr


app = endpoints.api_server([testapi],restricted=False)
```

ModelClasses.py

```
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
from google.appengine.ext import ndb



class test(EndpointsModel):

    user = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    passw = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: ID
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico


- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)


- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: api.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: endpoints
  version: latest

- name: pycrypto
  version: 1.0
```

[image]

[image]

You can see the request and response in pictures.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you testing the API running on localhost or have you deployed the API to App Engine already? If running on localhost you should remove the `hostname` parameter which is optional anyway, to make sure the requests are actually sent to localhost.

Comment: Thank you for your response i am running it on localhost.

Comment: It is giving me response now. But it is saying "503 Service Unavailable".

Comment: I figured out my problem and now it is working fine thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

@Scarygami Answere is correct. I have to remove the hostname because i am using it on local host.

Comment: I don't believe you should ever need hostname anymore anyway.